# check if the focus was changed by mouse press inside mousePressEvent

Tags: c++, qt

I have a widget and I want to run some function when the user presses a mouse on it. But I want to run it ONLY if the mouse press caused focus change. I tried the following:

```
void MyWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) 
{
    if (hasFocus()) // WRONG: I want to check whether the widget had focus before the mouse press, but it does not work, this always returns true
    { 
        //do something for which I need `event.pos()`
    }

    MyWidgetParent::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

but it does not work. `hasFocus()` inside `mousePressEvent()` is always true, it seems that focus gets changed before `mousePressEvent()` is called. On the other hand, I cannot implement this functionality in `focusInEvent` because I do not know the mouse `event.pos()` in it.

Any ideas how to work around this problem?

Comment: I'm *guessing* you are using Qt, but you don't actually say - you *should*, we are not mind readers.

Comment: It's actually in the tags but yes, would have been nice in the title.

Comment: Qt was in the tags and I do not think it is reasonable to mention all tags in the title too. Do you think I should mention C++ in the title too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a handler for a `QFocusEvent` (`focusInEvent`) and check if the `reason()` is a `MouseFocusReason`. You can save that in a variable and in the `QMouseEvent` you check and reset that variable. So if the element was focused by the mouse and you get a mouse event you know, that that mouse event caused the focus change.

Comment: Seems to me as the only solution that could work. Though I do not like it very much, it feels like a fragile hack based on the assumption that `focusInEvent()` with `reason==MouseFocusReason` is always followed by `mousePressEvent()`. Which seems as implementation details of Qt. But so far it works. Solution as this definitely should be covered by tests to prevent regressions.